# Strap.io: How to fetch multilingual data by slug?

Tags: node.js, strapi, headless-cms

I have two data streams for each language ( English & Swahili ) and both have their own slugs. When I want to get English data it's a piece of cake, I just do the obvious:

```
GET /services?slug=motor-vehicle
```

But whenever I try to replicate the same trick on the Swahili language by doing the following:

```
GET /services?slug=magari
```

It gives me an empty array.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Please have a look at the internationalization plugin documentation [here](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/i18n.html#%F0%9F%8C%8D-internationalization-i18n). It describes in detail what steps you need to perform for creating as well as fetching localized entries from the database.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using the internationalization plugin you also have to specified a language code otherwise strapi will fallback to the default language. That's why your query only works for the english slugs: slug=magari&_locale=en just wouldn't match anything.

Try:

```
GET /services?slug=magari&_locale=sw
```

Or the more generic approach... disable the language filter:

```
GET /services?slug=magari&_locale=all
```